# Play-2.2 Example @ManyToMany Relationship Java

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I was unable to find a complete example for designing a ManyToMany relationship with Play-2.2 in Java.
My Problem is, i can't get the Form-to-Model binding to work on my ManyToMany Relationship...

There are many users. A user can have many jobs. 
There are many jobs. A job can "have" many members/participants(users).

Job.java

```
@Entity
public class Job extends TimmeeyModel {

@Constraints.Required
@Column(unique = true)
public String jobName;


@ManyToMany(mappedBy="jobs")
public List<User> members = new ArrayList<User>();

public static Finder<Long,Job> find = new Finder<Long, Job>(Long.class,Job.class);

@Override
public Job create(){
    this.save();
    return this;
}

@Override
public Job update(Long id){
    Job oldJob = find.byId(id);
    oldJob.setJobName(this.getJobName());
    oldJob.setMembers(this.getMembers());
    oldJob.save();
    oldJob.refresh();
    return oldJob;
}
@Override
public void delete(){
    this.delete();
}


public String toString(){
    String userString ="";
    for (User user : members) {
        userString+=user.getUsername() +", ";
    }
    return jobName + ", " + id +" " + userString;
}

}
```

User.java

```
@Entity
public class User extends TimmeeyModel {

@Constraints.Required
@Column(unique = true)
public String username;
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
public List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<Job>();




public static Finder<Long, User> find = new Finder<Long, User>(Long.class, User.class);


public String getEmail(){
    return this.username + "@pool.math.tu-berlin.de";
}

@Override
public User create(){
    //jobs.add(Job.find.all().get(0));
    this.save();
    return this;
}

@Override
public  User update(Long id){
    User user = find.ref(id);
    user.setUsername(this.getUsername());
    user.setUsername(this.getUsername());
    user.save();
    user.refresh();
    return user;
}

public void delete(){
    this.delete();
}


public String toString(){
    String jobString = "";
    for (Job job : jobs) {
        jobString += job.toString() + ", ";

    }
    return "User Id: " + id + " "+username + "Jobs: " + jobString;
}
```

UserController.java

```
    public static Result  showCreate(){
    return ok(views.html.user.add.render(Job.find.all(), userForm));
}

public static Result create(){
    Map<String, String> newData = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Form<User> filledForm = userForm.bind(newData);
      if(filledForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest("Leider nein" + filledForm.toString());
      } else {
        String logString = filledForm.toString();
        User user = filledForm.get();
        user.create();
        return ok(user.toString() + logString);  
      }
}
```

The view scala template

```
@form(routes.Users.create()) {
 @inputText(userForm("username"))
@for((value,index) <- jobs.zipWithIndex ) {
    <input type="checkbox" name="jobs[]"     value="@value.getId()">@value.getJobName()</input>
}
```

i just cant get it to work. After submitting the Joblist of a user stays empty. But when i set the list "hardcoded" inside the user object, it stays there and works like expected. SO i don't think it is related to some db/config issue. SO i suspect there is something wrong while binding the form-data to the User-Model.
I also tried different version of the form like
@value.getJobName()
@value.getJobName()
@value.getJobName()
@value.getJobName()

Nothing works. So has anyone an idea what i doing wrong, or what i don't get about play!? Maybe it is impossible to do this without writing HUGE ammounts of boilerplate code in every Controller where i want to handle models with manyToMany relationships?
Because i know i could parse the form data in the controller "by hand" and force-put the jobs-List into the users. But this can not be the right way for such a MVC framework like play :-)

Thank you

By the way, there is not even ONE example/sample in the Play-Documentation/GitHub where the term "ManyToMany" occurs...

Really i just need some not totally fucked way to handle ManyToMany Relations ( if i can't use checkboxes.. Okay, if i should use something else, OK.... I just need some way for it to work)

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question myself. In short: It is NOT possible with Play! to autobind Objects from their identifiers to a List.

Maybe you will read something about custom Databinder or some magical form helpers.

The CustomDatabinder is good when you want to get a SINGLE complex Object mapped for example

User.java

public Job mainJob;

If you now enter the id of a Job into the User form, a custom Databinder is able to bind the data (if you provided one).
But this will not work for List

In fact the only thing is to use a little boilerplate code.

I did it that way

```
User user = filledForm.get();
        List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<Job>();
        for (Job job : user.getJobs()) {
            jobs.add(Job.find.byId(job.getId()));
        }
        user.create();
```

The form binder will generate a List of Jobs for the jobs List in the User. But these jobs are just "stubs" i had too iterate through the generated Jobs, and build a list with the real ones by searching for them in the Database..

It's not pretty, but also not too ugly.

Maybe this explanation can help others.